# С чего начать изучение php?

Tags: php

С чего начать изучение php?

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/ru/ лучше этого сайта по PHP пока не видел, и учебник и все функции и ещё бонусом примеры использования функций от юзеров

Comment: Неудивительно, ведь это официальный сайт PHP.

Comment: А вот для меня это как раз и удивительно, что официальный сайт является лучшим среди русскоязычных ресурсов, у других языков и фреймворков это редкость

Comment: @MasterAlex мы, наверное, в разных мирах живем.

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас есть опыт работы с HTML, в чем я ни капельки не сомневаюсь, то вам нужно попробовать поучить PHP [вот здесь](http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp). Если вам не понравится такое обучение, то есть более приятный способ выучить этот язык и другие на [этом англоязычном сайте](http://codecademy.com). Только я вам сначала советую там зарегистрироваться, и только потом приступать к обучению.

Comment: Зарегистрироваться, выучить английский, а потом приступать к обучению :)

Comment: @MasterAlex Ну, английский там не такой уж сложный. =) 
Если хочется, то можно и посидеть с каким-нибудь онлайн переводчиком и переводить непонятное. Я сам там выучил HTML, CSS, доучиваю JS ну и так далее. Мне показалось это простым, но люди разные бывают.

Comment: @smily_prg, проходил курсы по JS года 3,5 назад и перевод этого простого английского языка с гуглотранслейтом занимал 70-80% времени, потому что нельзя было примерно понять перевод, нужна 100% точность для понимания, что от тебя хотят, иначе ты неправильно сделаешь задание

Comment: @MasterAlex Полностью с тобой согласен на счет понимания задания.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.php.su/learnphp/
пошагово обьясняют что и как с примерами кода.

Comment: ...на PHP 5.0, ага

Comment: С примерами на PHP 4